# jQuery using multiple buttons of the same class to return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of entries generated by PHP, each in its own div and each with a unique ID. I'm trying to develop an AJAX call that can remove each entry based on their ID, however whenever I run the script below, it always returns 0.

```
<div>
    Some entry here
    <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
    Another entry here
    <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
// ... and so on

<script>
    $(".remove").click(function() {
        var id = $(".remove").attr('id');
        alert(id); // debug
        // AJAX call here
    });
</script>
```

Previously I tried the same thing except for the other way around - the id returned by PHP was in the class attribute and the id attribute had the value 'remove' and this only returned 0 for the first button. The second button didn't invoke the jQuery script at all.

How can I pass a unique ID to the same jQuery call?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); // $(this) refers to button that was clicked
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The vanilla option for future viewers.

1. Select all elements with class `remove`
2. Iterate through the elements, assigning a click handler
3. On click remove the parent element
4. Log the id to the console

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    for ( var i in Object.keys( buttons ) ) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function() {
            this.parentElement.remove();
            console.log(this.id);
        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<div>Some entry here
    <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>Another entry here
    <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use **[`this.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)** to get id of the element

```js
$(".remove").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Some entry here
  <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
  Another entry here
  <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".remove").on("click",function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `this` keyword to refer to the clicked element:

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    // OR
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```